# I'd like to archive files from Ubuntu to Windows between two computers on a shared home network

Tags: windows, ubuntu, network-shares, file-sharing

I have an old laptop running Ubuntu 9.10 which I use as a LAMP environment for web development, and I have a comfortable, powerful desktop computer with Windows 7 installed on it. These two are connected to a home router so both can access the internet.

I have been able to set up Samba so I can mount my Apache home directory so it is accessible from Windows and is mapped as a network drive.

What I'd like to do is access some Windows folders *from* Linux so I could automatically create backups (with cron scripts) of my work to physically different locations on the Windows box. Perhaps at a later time I'd set up a local Subversion repository but I'd love to keep backups of that on the Windows drives too.

Using Ubuntu's Places/Network menu I can see my desktop but I'm unable to log in to that despite having created the corrent username and password on Windows. All I can get is the following error message: "Unable to mount location. Failed to retrieve share list from server."

What could be misconfigurated?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I can't write comments. Just a couple of Qs for you)

1. Have you tried *Places* -> *Connect to Server*?
2. Have you tried connecting to the Windows machine from another Windows machine? (Eliminates possible problems with the winbox firewall or networking components.)

Comment: I tried the _Connect to Server_ as a Windows share, but it was unsuccessful. The username, the domain and the password were all correct but instead of getting any (error) message the connection dialog just reappeared after click the _Connect_ button.

Currently I don't have access to other Windows machines here.

Comment: Hey, sorry, when I wrote the reply I didn't realise how long it'd been since you asked! If you don't have other Win machines then I guess you're on a workgroup - try again without using a domain name. On my system that's `Connect to Server...` select `Service type: Windows share` type the name of the Windows machine without any slashes for the server, eg. `Server: jonathan` and then the name of the share, eg. `Share: incoming`. Nothing else is necessary... any better?